# How do I get Bootstrap formatting to apply to Html.EnumDropDownListFor()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As the question states, I have a very simple Asp.Net MVC 5 app that I'm using Bootstrap 3.1 on with the following Helper,

`@this.Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`.

However the control is not formatted the same as the Textboxes on the same page.  Am I just using the wrong css class or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for `htmlAttributes`, you can just pass an anonymous object as a second argument to the [EnumDropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn550750%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.  I only added `htmlAttributes` because all of the Textboxes that Scaffolding generated have it.